# Winsock Port Listener

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, winsock

I've done a TCP port listener. it works when i connect to it locally using client with `127.1.1.0` and a port that listener is bound to accept connection. can you make it to listen to any IP that connects through that port and would it be possible to listen to a second client port that is accepting from server?

Comment: does TCP listener only work for local ip communication or any ip coming from internet?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify [INADDR_ANY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737550%28VS.85%29.aspx) to bind. You cannot bind the same socket to multiple ports, but you can certainly create multiple sockets, each listening to a different port.

Comment: Alternatively, bind() to specific IPs that you are expecting client connections to arrive from.  INADDR_ANY binds to all available IPs, but if you have multiple IPs installed, and clients will only come from a smaller subset of them (say, from the Internet IP and not a private LAN IP), then you can reduce the number of bound IPs used.